# Datatables.net datatable.page.info() - recordsTotal and recordsFiltered

Tags: php, datatables, client-side

I am not using server side processing. I want to show the table data such as start, end and recordsTotal. It works great except when filters are applied to the table. It still shows the total rows, not the filtered row count.

Code that works without filters is

```
$("#data-kt-table-info").html("Showing " + (datatableInfo.start+1) + " to " + datatableInfo.end + " of " + datatableInfo.recordsTotal + " rows");
```

I tried the following code to get the filtered count without any luck:

```
$("#data-kt-table-info").html("Showing " + (datatableInfo.start+1) + " to " + datatableInfo.end + " of " + datatableInfo.recordsFiltered + " rows");
```

Is this not working because I am not using server side? How can I get the filtered row count? Thank you for the help, much appreciated!

Comment: Check the valid values for [`page.info()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/page.info()). One of them is `recordsDisplay`. I think you need that, not `recordsFiltered`.

Comment: That was it! I was having a stressful day and blanked out on even checking the page.info(). Thank you, I appreciate it so much!